# Euler's formula [Zorich's book]

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

[image]

This is an excerpt from Zorich's book and I'd like to clarify one moment from it because he does not explain why this step is valid.

We know the definition of $e^z$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ then we plug in $z=iy$ and we obtain  the series $$1+\dfrac{1}{1!}(iy)+\dfrac{1}{2!}(iy)^2+\dfrac{1}{3!}(iy)^3+\dfrac{1}{4!}(iy)^4+\dots;$$

then somehow he claims that it is the sum of two series $$\left( 1-\frac{1}{2!}y^2+\frac{1}{4!}y^4-\dots\right)+i\left( \dfrac{1}{1!}y-\dfrac{1}{3!}y^3+\dfrac{1}{5!}y^5-\dots\right).$$

Can anyone explain to me why this manipulation is valid?

What is the reasoning beyond that? Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: It's due to the fact that $i^2=-1$, list the terms out.

Comment: Also because the series is absolutely convergent, so we can rearrange and split up  terms.

Comment: @TheBestMagician, your answer has not nothing in common with my question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, can you be more specific please? If you can write it as a separate answer that would be great!

Comment: $i^n$ and Moivre's formula should help .

Comment: In the series expansion $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iy)^n}{n!}$, group together all the even power terms, and all the odd power terms (this rearrangement is valid due to absolute convergence as mentioned by thomas). Repeatedly using $i^2=-1$ will show within 2 lines of algebra that the even power terms gives you $\cos(y)$ and the odd power terms become $i\sin(y)$. I'm not going to write out the algebra for this. You should  really do so by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a_{n}=\frac{(yi)^n}{n!}$ there are some things you need to notice:

$$\begin{align}a_{2n}&=\frac{i^{2n}y^{2n}}{(2n)!}=(-1)^n\frac{y^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
a_{2n+1} &=\frac{(iy)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=(-1)^n i \frac{y^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\end{align} $$

This is because $i^{2n}=(i^2)^n=(-1)^n.$

The other thing you need to know is why you can do:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2n+1}.$$

You would be right to be skeptical, because it is not true in general. For example, it is not true when $a_n=(-1)^n\frac1{n+1}.$

But you *can* do it, and in general can re-order and partition the series in any way, when $\sum_{n} |a_n|$ converges - that is, if the series converges absolutely.

And here, $|a_n|=\frac{|y|^n}{n!}$ and $$\sum |a_n|=e^{|y|}.$$